# 2D Kuramoto-Sivashinski equation written in components

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, laplacian

I could find 1D and 2D form of Kuramoto-Sivashinski equation. See e.g. [2D equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kuramoto-SivashinskyEquation.html).

$ u_{t} + \nabla^{2}u + \nabla^{4}u + \frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2 = 0 $

But I could not find explicit components expression of this equation. I am quite sure that biharmonic operator should be in 2D [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation)

$ \Delta^{2}= \nabla^{4} = \partial_{xxxx} + 2\partial_{xxyy} + \partial_{yyyy} $.

But I am not sure how $ |\nabla u|^{2} $ term looks like. If we denote x and y components of "velocity" $ u(x,y,t) $ as $ w $ and $ v $ I guess system of partial equations should be like

$ w_{t} = -ww_{x}-vw_{y} - w_{xx} - w_{yy} - w_{xxxx} - 2w_{xxyy}-w_{yyyy}$
$ v_{t} = -wv_{x}-vv_{y} - v_{xx} - v_{yy} - v_{xxxx} - 2v_{xxyy}-v_{yyyy}$

1D Kuramoto equation should be then (I am sure about that)
$ w_{t} = -ww_{x} - w_{xx} - w_{xxxx}$. Can somebody show, if component expansion is correct?

Comment: In 2D, $\nabla u = (u_x, u_y)$ and therefore $|\nabla u|^2 = u_x^2 + u_y^2$.

Comment: @HansEngler I noticed from your comment, that $u$ is actually a scalar, not vector! So whole form of Kuramoto-Sivashinski equation should be:
$ u_{t}= \frac{1}{2}(-u_{x}^{2}−u_{y}^{2})−u_{xx}−u_{yy}−u_{xxxx}−2u_{xxyy}−u_{yyyy} $ ?

Comment: That is how I understand it, too. Note however that some people consider the equation $u_t + \Delta u + \Delta^2 u = \frac{1}{2} |\nabla u|^2$ instead, or they leave off the factor $\frac{1}{2}$. Also note that in 1-D the function $w = u_x$ satisfies $w_t + w_{xx} + w_{xxxx} + w w_x = 0$.